# 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am receiving the error of SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
if (isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
        $nome     = trim(strip_tags($_POST['nome']));
        $usuario  = trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario']));
        $email    = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $senha    = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));
        $cpf      = trim(strip_tags($_POST['cpf']));
        $rg       = trim(strip_tags($_POST['rg']));

        $select = "INSERT INTO registro (nome, usuario, email, senha, cpf, rg)
                                    VALUES (:nome, :usuario, email, :senha, :cpf, :rg)";

        try{
            $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
            $result->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':usuario', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':senha', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':email', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':cpf', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':rg', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();

            if($contar>0){
                echo 'logado com sucesso';
            }else{
                echo "Os dados digitados estão incorretos";
            }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a `:` missing in your query.

Comment: You're missing a `:` for the `email` parameter in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Query

```
   $select = "INSERT INTO registro (nome, usuario, email, senha, cpf, rg)
                                    VALUES (:nome, :usuario, email, :senha, :cpf, :rg)";
```

**After change** **Missing : in email**

```
  $select = "INSERT INTO registro (nome, usuario, email, senha, cpf, rg)
                                        VALUES (:nome, :usuario, :email, :senha, :cpf, :rg)";
```